# DOM IDBDatabase Exception 8 in indexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

I'm reading Professional JavaScript for Web Developers 3rd edition and trying examples.
In chapter23,there have a demo: IndexedDBExample02.htm. it have an error:DOM IDBDatabase Exception 8 please help ,thank you very much!

```
(function(){

    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB,
        request,
        store,
        database,
        users = [
            {
                username: "007",
                firstName: "James",
                lastName: "Bond",
                password: "foo"
            },
            {
                username: "ace",
                firstName: "John",
                lastName: "Smith",
                password: "bar"
            }                
        ];

    request = indexedDB.open("example");
    request.onerror = function(event){
        alert("Something bad happened while trying to open: " + event.target.errorCode);
    };
    request.onsuccess = function(event){
        database = event.target.result;
        initializeDatabase();
    };    

    function initializeDatabase(){
        if (database.version != "1.0"){
            request = database.setVersion("1.0");
            request.onerror = function(event){
                alert("Something bad happened while trying to set version: " + event.target.errorCode);
            };
            request.onsuccess = function(event){
                store = database.createObjectStore("users", { keyPath: "username" });
                var i=0,
                    len = users.length;

                while(i < len){
                    store.add(users[i++]);
                }

                alert("Database initialized for first time. Database name: " + database.name + ", Version: " + database.version);
            };
        } else {
            alert("Database already initialized. Database name: " + database.name + ", Version: " + database.version);

            request = database.transaction("users").objectStore("users").get("007");
            request.onsuccess = function(event){
                alert(event.target.result.firstName);
            };
        }
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

- setVersion is deprecated
- versions are ints, not strings (and not floats)
- using the database variable in your scope does not guarantee its state, you should only be using it in a callback
- you can only modify your schema within the context of a transaction used in the onupgradeneeded callback.

Comment: versions are ints, not floats

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to read some blogs about the subject. The way you are working is deprecated as Josh Froelich mentioned. I wrote some [blogs](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/search/label/IndexedDB) about it, I advice you to read them first before moving on with the indexeddb API.